# Length of varbinary(max) filestream on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, filestream, varbinary, datalength

Is there some efficient way how to get length of data in "varbinary(max) filestream" column?
I found only samples with conversion to varchar and then calling the "LEN" function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT
      length = DATALENGTH(Name),
      Name 
FROM 
      Production.Product 
ORDER BY 
      Name
```

*"Returns the **number of bytes** used to represent any expression."*

T-SQL and quote taken from MSDN's [DATALENGTH (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) library.