# Reading 200MB file from db throws Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, sqlcommand, varbinarymax

I am attempting to query the database and pull excel files that could be as large as 1 million rows *(~200MB)* stored as `varbinary` and pass it through a validator.

Our build server has *6GB* of memory and a load-balanced processor and during runtime comes nowhere near maxing out the CPU or Memory.

Yet, after about 40 seconds the process throws an `OutOfMemoryException`.

**Here's the stack trace:**

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.get_Value()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_ByteArray()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Value()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueFromSqlBufferInternal(SqlBuffer data, _SqlMetaData metaData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteExecuteScalar(SqlDataReader ds, Boolean returnSqlValue)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at eConfirmations.DataService.FileServices.FileDataService.GetFileContent(Guid fileId) in d:\w1\3\s\Source\eConfirmations.DataService\FileServices\FileDataService.cs:line 157
...
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.get_Value()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_ByteArray()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Value()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueFromSqlBufferInternal(SqlBuffer data, _SqlMetaData metaData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteExecuteScalar(SqlDataReader ds, Boolean returnSqlValue)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at eConfirmations.DataService.FileServices.FileDataService.GetFileContent(Guid fileId) in d:\w1\3\s\Source\eConfirmations.DataService\FileServices\FileDataService.cs:line 157
```

**And here's the my code that throws the exception:**

```
    private byte[] GetFileContent(Guid fileId)
    {
        byte[] content;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["eConfirmationsDatabase"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;
                sqlCommand.CommandText = $"SELECT Content FROM dbo.[File] WHERE FileId = '{fileId}'";
                sqlConnection.Open();
                content = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];
                sqlConnection.Close();
                sqlCommand.Dispose();
            }
            sqlConnection.Dispose();
        }
        return content;
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way to pull back this data or can we update a setting on our build server to avoid this error?

Comment: How much heap space does the C# environment have available?

Comment: @Carcigenicate [C# Increase Heap Size - Is It Possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2325396/402022).

Comment: Or a SqlDataReader with the SequentialAccess flag would allow you to   stream the data.

Comment: It looks like a few other people has gor mysterious OutOfMemoryExceptions on the same point. For instance see [Why do I get a System.OutOfMemoryException using NHibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170293/why-do-i-get-a-system-outofmemoryexception-using-nhibernate). None of the search results I found have a solution. I suspect there is an artificial constraint for the size of the result. Btw, you know you are double - actually triple 
- disposing, right?

Comment: @Theraot Triple disposing was to make sure there were no memory leaks

Comment: I know it may be a "duhh" but have you checked a level up in your code to see if what's calling this is somehow looping?  I can't tell you how many times I've found bugs in code where the same function was called more than once unnecessarily, but the stack trace didn't reflect it.

Comment: @CDove thanks for the input, I'm sure this is only running once and not looping through. I just can't speak for the SqlDataReader class and what it's doing behind the scenes

Comment: I would recommend instead of returning a big byte array, send in a target stream to this function and write to that.

Comment: Shouldn't the first parameter in `GetBytes` by 0 rather than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here's what's happening:

Because this is running on a 32-bit build, the maximum memory allocation is 2GB but I'm still coming nowhere near that threshold.

According to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595061/outofmemoryexception-while-populating-memorystream-256mb-allocation-on-16gb-sys) that is very similar to my situation, the .NET framework restricts objects to a limit of `256MB` in memory.

So even though my file is only 200MB, `byte[]`s and `MemoryStreams` expand by powers of 2 until they reach the 256MB necessary. When they expand, they create a new instance of the appropriate size and copy the old data over to the new one, *effectively multiplying the memory usage by 3* which causes the exception.

[MSDN has an example of how to retrieve a large file using a FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(v=vs.110).aspx), but instead of a FileStream, I use a static byte[] pre-initialized to the size of my data using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748165/length-of-varbinarymax-filestream-on-sql-server-2008).

**Here is my final solution:**

```
    public File GetFileViaFileIdGuid(Guid fileId)
    {
        File file = new File();
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
        using (var sourceSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = sourceSqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandText = $"SELECT FileName, FileExtension, UploadedDateTime, DATALENGTH(Content) as [ContentLength] FROM dbo.[File] WHERE FileId = '{fileId}'";
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;
                sourceSqlConnection.Open();

                var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    file.FileId = fileId;
                    file.FileExtension = reader["FileExtension"].ToString();
                    file.FileName = reader["FileName"].ToString();
                    file.UploadedDateTime = (DateTime)reader["UploadedDateTime"];
                    file.Content = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(reader["ContentLength"])];
                }

                reader.Close();
                sourceSqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        file.Content = GetFileContent(file.FileId, file.Content.Length);
        return file;
    }
```

**And to fetch the Content:**

```
    private byte[] GetFileContent(Guid fileId, int contentLength)
    {
        int outputSize = 1048576;
        int bufferSize = contentLength + outputSize;
        byte[] content = new byte[bufferSize];
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;
                sqlCommand.CommandText = $"SELECT Content FROM dbo.[File] WHERE FileId = '{fileId}'";
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        int startIndex = 0;
                        long returnValue = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, content, startIndex, outputSize);
                        while (returnValue == outputSize)
                        {
                            startIndex += outputSize;
                            returnValue = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, content, startIndex, outputSize);
                        }
                    }
                }

                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        return content;
    }
```

Comment: If your validator runs in a separate process, you can stream the file directly to disk or pipe the stream to the other process.  That lets you grab the file in tiny chunks.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Unfortunately not. I'm using `Aspose.Cells` to create an excel file in memory and it will fail if it doesn't have the entire content

Comment: Is the reason you are building a 32-bit app because of the `Aspose.Cells` library?  As a somewhat related data point, I found the largest 32 bit C# app ends up being around 1.4 GB before running into memory issues.  Remember that you also have to have room to garbage collect, and there are multiple GC buckets--if any of them fill up you will get an `OutOfMemoryException`.  Lastly, if you use WinForms and attempt to draw something that is smaller than 1 pixel you also get an `OutOfMemoryException`.  That was the most surprising thing I ran across. in dealing with memory problems.